# How to Find List of Files with Certain Extension From an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs

I have been working through a nodeschool tutorial: *learnyounode*, which can be found [here](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode). I was working on challenge five (*FILTERED LS*).

The challenge was this:

> Create a program that prints a list of files in a given directory, filtered by the extension of the files. You will be provided a directory  name as the first argument to your program (e.g. '/path/to/dir/') and a  file extension to filter by as the second argument.

This is my code so far:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');

    extname = '.' + path.extname(process.argv[3]);

    console.log(extname);

    fs.readdir(process.argv[2].toString(), function(err, list) {

       if (err) {
          throw err;
       }

       list.filter(extname);
       console.log(list);
    });
```

How do I effectively filter out all files that are given as a console argument? Does it have something to do with path.extname? If so, how? I have tried using `.filter()`, but that does not seem to work. Would someone also be able to explain to me how `.filter()` works as well as its arguments as I have found documentation to be a bit confusing. Finally, is there a better way to output the elements of an array on separate lines than `console.log()`?

Thanks

Comment: Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your usage of .filter() - instead of providing the extension name as the argument of the function, you need to supply a callback that will be called on each element of the list, and only return the values that pass a specific test (in this case the file extension is present in the string).

For example

```
var filelist = ['woohoo.txt', 'aha.pdf', 'wahoo.txt'];
var extension = '.txt';

var x = filelist.filter(function(file){
    return file.indexOf(extension) !== -1;
});

console.log(x); // expected output: ['woohoo.txt', 'wahoo.txt']
```

Javascript uses closures, and so the variable "extension" is accessible in the function scope, since it is available in the parent

Answer (score 3):

You are using `.filter` incorrectly. This method is receiving a function argument which is being applied to each of the array elements and decides if this elements should remain in the new list. What you did was to supply this function a string, but how should it use this string to filter the array elements? Should it take the elements that has this string as a prefix? Should it take the elements that doesn't contain this string?

You should determine the way that your program would choose which string to keep and which to discard.

In your case, you are looking to filter by an extension (or postfix). The function you can pass for this purpose might be, for example:

```
list.filter(file => file.endsWith(extname));
```

This would pass file by file and select only those that ends with the given extension, as you wanted.

the problem with andrewkodesgood's answer is that the given extension doesn't have to be placed at the end of the file name, but also in the middle or even the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Just one other possible way.

```
let files = [
    '/Users/dave/Movies/2021-09-16 08-29-25.mp4',
    '/Users/dave/Downloads/video.mp4',
    '/System/Library/Movies/Regular.mov',
    '/System/Library/Movies/Regular.ttf',
    '/System/Library/Movies/Regular.txt',
    '/System/Library/Movies/Regular.pdf'
];

let filtered = files.filter(file => ['mp4', 'mov'].includes(file.split('.').pop()));
console.log(filtered);
```

Outputs

```
/*
["/Users/dave/Movies/2021-09-16 08-29-25.mp4", "/Users/dave/Downloads/video.mp4", "/System/Library/Movies/Regular.mov"]
*/
```